# php file submit button not sending response

Tags: php, html

In my code there is an html form. I want to send response via email and display a line "your message was send" on clicking the button, but its not working ... nothing happens when I click send response button.

Please help ... thank you

```
<?php 
 if (isset($_post['send'])) { 
  $ToEmail = 'abc@gmail.com'; 
  $EmailSubject = 'Site contact form'; 
  $mailheader = "From: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n"; 
  $mailheader .= "Reply-To: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n"; 
  $mailheader .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n"; 
  $check_list1 = $_POST['check_list1'];
   if ($check_list1 != 'Yes') {
     $check_list1 = 'No';
   }
  $check_list2 = $_POST['check_list2'];
   if ($check_list2 != 'Yes') {
    $check_list2 = 'No';
   }

  $MESSAGE_BODY = "Date ".$_POST["dat"]."";
  $MESSAGE_BODY .= "Location ".$_POST["location"]."";

  mail($ToEmail, $EmailSubject, $MESSAGE_BODY, $mailheader) or die ("Failure"); 
  ?> 
 Your message was sent
<?php 

} else { 
?> 
 <h1><center>Meeting Invitation</center></h1>
   <form action="my.php" method="post">
      You are invited for the meeting on company crisis
       proposed dates are :<br><br>

    Date &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Time<br>

    10 jan,2015 &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; 10.00 am<input type = "radio" name = "dat" <?php if    

   (isset($dat) && $dat=="val1") echo "checked";?> value = "val1" checked="true" ><br>

    12 feb,2015 &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; 12.15 am<input type = "radio" name = "dat" <?php if 

   (isset($dat) && $dat=="val2") echo "checked";?> value = "val2" ><br><br>

    Proposed locations are :<br>

    Location 1 : &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Islamabad <input type = "radio" name = "location" <?php if 

  (isset($location) && $location=="val1") echo "checked";?>  value = "val1" checked="true" ><br>

    Location 2 : &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Rawalpindi <input type = "radio" name = "location" <?php if 

     (isset($location) && $location=="val2") echo "checked";?>  value = "val2" ><br><br>

        Do you want travel facility ? &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;

     <input type="checkbox" name="check_list1" value="yes"> <br><br>

        Do you want hotel facility ? &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;

        <input type="checkbox" name="check_list2" value="yes"> <br><br><br>

        <input type="button" name="send" value="Send Response">

        <input type="reset" >

   </form>
```

Comment: There is no `$_post` variable, it should be `$_POST`. PHP variable names are case sensitive.

Comment: thank you for correction but its still not working

Comment: what do you want to send? Email field, etc. are not defined by form...

Comment: You have not closed your else condition , check my answer

Comment: @654:from where you getting "$_POST["email"]";?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input type="button" name="send" value="Send Response">
```

Type needs to be **submit** unless you have a separate event handler in your Javascript to send the data.

```
<input type="submit" name="send" value="Send Response">
```

Otherwise *no event is fired* except the mouse clickies.

And yeah your PHP needs `$_POST` not `$_post` but that's not really what's affecting the send button being unresponsive.

Answer (score 1):

Basic PHP 101: Variable names are case sensitive

```
 if (isset($_post['send'])) { 
            ^^^^^--- undefined variable
```

It should be `$_POST`. If you had display_errors and error_reporting turned on, you'd have been warned about using an undefined variable, and treating that undefined variable as an array. The debug options should never be off on a devel/debug system in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You have not closed your `else` condition

at the end of the file close the else tag

```
</form>
<?php }
```

And follow `Marc B`  and `Deryck's` guide lines

Comment: i have closed else part .. it was mistake while uploading question thank you :)